# Is there a "standard" for how eigenvectors are returned when there are duplicate eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

Matlab will scale all eigenvectors to be unit eigenvectors. However, when a matrix has an eigenspace that is a linear combination of multiple vectors, how are those vectors chosen? I was assuming that free variables would be set to 1s and 0s, and then scaled to unit vectors, but that does not seem to be the case.

```
M=[3 2 4;2 0 2;4 2 3];
[A,B]= eig(M);

    -0.49410  -0.55805   0.66667
A = -0.47202   0.81614   0.33333
     0.73011   0.14998   0.66667
```

while I was assuming something simpler like:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & 0 & \frac{2}{3}\\
 \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{3}\\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{3}\\
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

I know that mathematically the values that I was assuming are no less accurate since I can combine them to produce the Matlab vectors, but I would like to know what they choose, and possibly why, to ease testing if my calculations are correct.

Comment: You generally won't see floating-point-equal eigenvalues except in highly degenerate situations (such as if you ask for the solution to the eigenproblem for a multiple of the identity) even when the true eigenvalues are duplicate. In particular Matlab is *not* finding eigenvectors through a Gaussian elimination-type procedure like you do by hand. It is finding them iteratively, at the same time as the eigenvalues. The choice of the algorithm used depends on the properties of the matrix you input (for example Matlab checks for symmetry).

Comment: That said, you may be able to check your hand calculations by doing something like e=eig(A); rref(A-e(k)*eye(size(A,1))). But if there is some error in the eigenvalue e(k) then this may erroneously come out as the identity matrix. You may also run into condition-number-related issues (for an approximate eigenvalue $\lambda$, cond($A-\lambda I$) is very large).

Comment: Also, in this particular case I can explain the behavior: for a symmetric matrix, Matlab will seek out orthogonal eigenvectors, even in the presence of duplicate eigenvalues. Your first and second eigenvectors are not orthogonal.